# Creating a generic typed Dict derivative

Tags: python, python-typing

I'm trying to create a dict-like type with `setdefault()` in place of `get()`, with pre-defined default type. But it also should not be a pointer to same object all the time.

Problem is, I don't understand how to instantiate a var given a corresponding TypeVar.

Here is pseudo code:

```py
F = TypeVar('F')
T = TypeVar('T')


class AutoExpandingDict(Dict[F, T]):

    def __getitem__(self, key: F) -> T:
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = new T()
        return super(AutoExpandingDict, self).__getitem__(key)
```

how do I make `new T()` work?

Expected use is:

```py
stats = AutoExpandingDict[str, AutoExpandingDict[str, RequestTimer]]()
```

where RequestTimer is a class which records some statistics, then

```py
def _api_request(method = 'GET', endpoint = None):
    ...
    with stats[method][endpoint]:
        ...
        
        response = self.session.request(method, f'{self.base_url}{api_path}{url_params_encoded}', ...)
        ...
    ...
```

There will be other uses aside from `RequestTimer`, and I don't want to copy-paste a lot of classes with just different names or repeat `setdefault` with magic parameters every time (if it will be a plain `dict`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic type parameters in Python are "erased" at runtime, so you can't access the value of `T`. Consider this:

```py
A = TypeVar("A", covariant=True)

class Foo(Generic[A]):
    def __init__(self, something: A) -> None:
        self._something = something

    def do_something(self):
        [a_type] = get_params_somehow(self)
        print(a_type)

class X:
    pass

class Y(X):
    pass

foo1: Foo[X] = Foo(Y())
foo2: Foo[Y] = Foo(Y())

x = some().com().pu().ta() + tion()
foo3 = Foo(x)
```

`foo1` an `foo2` were created in the same way, and they can't access the information about their type (without resorting to hacks with `inspect`).

With `foo3`, the type of `x` will be *inferred* by a type checker, so `foo3` can't really know what it is at runtime, and the type might be different with `mypy`, `pyright`, `pyre` etc. Again, the types (not runtime type, but the type hint stuff) are just "in the type checker's head".

If you only intend to construct the dict in the `AutoExpandingDict[str, AutoExpandingDict[str, RequestTimer]]()` manner, though, you could override [`__class_getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__class_getitem__) or make a custom metaclass. But that is not very intuitive and probably overkill

---

What you might want to do is provide a factory, similar to [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
class AutoExpandingDict(Dict[F, T]):
    def __init__(self, factory: Callable[[], T]):
        self._factory = factory

    def __getitem__(self, key: F) -> T:
        if key not in self:
            self[key] = self._factory()
        return super().__getitem__(key)
```

For example:

```py
stats: AutoExpandingDict[str, AutoExpandingDict[str, RequestTimer]] = 
AutoExpandingDict(lambda: AutoExpandingDict(RequestTimer))
```

---

Maybe you just want a `defaultdict`?

Comment: yes, probably I can do with defaultdict if init is unavoidable. Thanks! (+1d)

Comment: okay, I find this syntax somewhat noisy, but it'll do for now `stats: dict[str, dict[str, RequestTimer]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(RequestTimer))`